# Xamarin Push Notification, Handling the remote notification once the app becomes active

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I know how to send notifications to my iOS devices through PushSharp.  However, once I do and the app is inactive, I am looking to find a way to handle the push notification once the app becomes active again.

In other words, I want to be able to see what item they clicked on and be able to show data relevant to that.

Here is a link for reference, it does what I am asking for, but only when the app is active.
http://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/push-notifications-in-ios-with-monotouch/

Answer (score 2):

Whats the problem?

You have two scenarions:

1. Push-notification received when app is not launching. If use tap on notification, app will get data in `FinishedLaunching` handler;
2. Push-notification received when app is launching. App will get data in `ReceivedRemoteNotification` handler.

Article in your question shows that `processNotification` is the same in both scenarios. It shows how to read alert (text)/badge (count)/sound fields and your own custom payload.